# C/C++ - создание графического интерфейса

Tags: c++, c, ооп, gui

Недавно захотелось начать свой проект, идея есть - а вот с реализацией встал вопрос, в частности с созданием интерфейса.
Я хочу проект писать на Си/C++ и при этом планирую использовать MS Visual Studio 2013. Возможно вы скажете сразу, что бы я использовал Qt, но я его не хочу трогать по двум причинам:

1. В универе требуют MSVS, курсач на нем будет и т.д.
2. Хочу все-таки разобраться для начала с технологиями от Microsoft.

Так вот, немного пошарил в нете, понял что есть такие штуки, как WinForms и WPF. Еще так же есть вариант winAPI. И вот тут у меня ступор - где, что и как?
Помогите разобраться, какие технологии применяются для создания интерфейсов с пом.С++ в MSVS; что лучше использовать на сегодняшний день? А так же посоветуйте нормальную литературу на этот счет.

Проект в рамках университета (небольшая программка по электротехнике для расчета всяких величин по заданой схеме), если это важно.

И все же повторюсь в своем вопросе: *что нужно знать и что нужно изучать, что бы начать писать GUI на С++ с пом. Visual Studio?*

Спасибо!

Comment: На сегодняшний день лучше вообще не писать графические интерфейсы на C/C++.

А для обучения при первой же возможности надо уходить с винды.

Если требуют курсач с MSVS, но можете сменить тему курсача на что-нибудь неграфическое -- меняйте.

Comment: WPF - это вообще не про С++. Winforms в общем-то тоже, хотя завести его на С++ можно. Правда, если мне не изменяет память, это будет С++/CLI, что далеко не то же самое, что и собственно С++

Comment: Согласен, и честно - я бы только "за", к примеру писать на том же python! Но задача, к сожалению, поставлена так, что нужно(!) писать все на С++ (т.к. изучается конкретно этот язык), с использованием инструмента MSVS(вопрос - а Visual studio - это инструмент?).
Вот поэтому и встал такой вопрос - что нужно знать для написания GUI с пом.С++ и майкрософтовского продукта.

Comment: Окей. А для чего WPF? Просто, на сколько я понял, что его можно использовать и для C++. Хотя с гугле почти 100% от общего кол-ва запросов выдает WPF в связке с C#! 
Ага, на сколько я понял: WinForms == C++/CLI? То есть мне нужно изучить C++/CLI, что бы уметь писать GUI?

Comment: Есть еще MFC, старый как то, что бывает старым, и лучше бы вам его не откапывать. И [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/), который на слуху и, кажется, я слышал о нем неплохие отзывы.

Comment: >нужно(!) писать все на С++ (т.к. изучается конкретно этот язык)

ну если вы изучаете именно С++, то требование может быть вполне логичным

>Visual studio - это инструмент?

а почему нет? другое дело, что зацикленность именно на этом инструменте несколько удивляет - есть много других IDE. Вероятно, ваши преподы просто требуют от вас то, с чем сами знакомы

Теоретически (и практически) можно написать что-нибудь с помощью сплошного Win API, не, уверяю вас, намучаетесь. Это позапрошлый век

Comment: >А для чего WPF

для удобного создания визуальных свистелок-перделок, привлекательных и удобных интерфейсов (нет, это не сарказм, wpf - вполне годная технология). Но используется он в основном в связке с C# и VB. Насчет С++/CLI точно не помню (может и его туда можно впихнуть), но это другая история (еще раз подчеркну С++/CLI != C++)

>на сколько я понял: WinForms == C++/CLI

вы неверно поняли. Winforms (как и WPF) способен работать с любым CLR-совместимым языком (не забивайте себе голову этим, важно, что чистый С++ в их число не входит)

Comment: > зацикленность именно на этом инструменте несколько удивляет

@DreamChild, да ладно, вы не видели ситуации, когда не слишком сведущий во всем этом нашем программировании человек принимает лабы строго по методичке, где сказано "Запустите MSVS. Нажмите на меню *Файл*...." ?

Comment: @Nofate ♦ я просто неверно выразился. Разумеется, меня это не удивляет, однако такая практика неверна. Вытекает она, судя по всему, из того, что препод не знаком ни с чем другим, и не хочет переучиваться, вот и принимает только то, с чем знаком сам

Comment: Что касается MSVC и непосредственно технологий Microsoft в связке с C++ - это монструозный MFC, вещь замороченная и в ней тебе поможет гугл в связке с MSDN, литературы в инете много. Что касается сишных GUI библиотек - Qt, wxWidgets, GTK - все они прекрасно собираются под MS C++ (единственное, не знаю как в 13 студии), Qt думаю более перспективный. Что касается WinForms и WPF - это по части .NET Framework, если ты выбрал C++, это тебе не подойдет изначально. По поводу литературы увы ничего сказать не могу - по Qt4 была в свое время книжка, но мне хватало их документации, она у них отличная.

Comment: @madrabbit
Поправлю - Qt не сишный ни разу)

Для Qt, как легкое введение, хорош М.Шлее, если учитывать новый синтаксис сигналов/слотов и то, что теперь нельзя наследоваться от QThread. В остальном - действительно неплохая документация.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое, что вам ближе - это MFC. WinForms - это не С++, это C++/CLI, который работает на платформе MS .Net Framework.

Беда MFC в том, что это тонкая прослойка над WinAPI там шаг влево-шаг вправо от идеологии фреймворка - пропасть.

Писать годные интерфейсы можно и нужно. Но, к счастью или несчастью, Qt здесь почти безальтернативен. Пусть он превносит в язык расширения в виде сигналов-слотов, как следствие - предобработки исходного кода MOC'ом, но это действительно юзабельный бриллиант в мире C++.

В академических целях, желательно овладевать чистым C++, в разумных пределах - WinAPI. Реальные более-менее сложные, переносимые интерфейсы можно писать wxWidget, GTKmm и иже с ними, just for fun.

Но Qt - это настоящее и будущее C++)

ЗЫ Плагин Qt позволяет писать из-под MSVS. Однако, студия враждебна к юникоду.

Comment: Ага, окей, как раз вот сейчас столкнулся с такой штукой, как MFC. Я так понимаю, что это самый стоящий выбор из всего того, что было предложено выше?
Еще вопрос - MFC - это прослойка на winAPI. То есть мне надо сначала изучить winAPI, после чего я смогу писать GUI с пом. MFC? 
И что значит "шаг влево-шаг вправо от идеологии фреймворка - пропасть." - то есть код работать не будет?

Comment: И еще один вопрос - если не брать в расчет MFC (хотя я так понял, что это лучший вариант для меня), то есть еще такие кросс-платформенные технологии, как, к примеру wxWidget. Я про нее читал малеха, но не совсем понял - это отдельная библиотека со своим набором ф-ий для создания граф.интерфейса на С++? И можно ли ее использовать в MSVS? 
И нужно ли знать для wxWidget winAPI?

Comment: @Hamsternik
Нет, стоящий здесь будет Qt, wxWidgets и GTKmm (по убыванию). А MFC хорош при определенных задачах или мелких набросках. Или как корпоративный стандарт для несчастных программистов, но хитрых менеджеров, закупивших MSVS Professional и выше =)

Код будет работать. Только попариться придется, либо натягивая структуру MFC-проекта на нестандартную фичу, либо опускаясь практически до голого API системы. К примеру, недавно я столкнулся с необходимостью запихнуть сплиттер в диалоговое окно. Это три строчки на Qt или три хитрых класса (наследников) на MFC. Убил часов 5-6 в целом на дзен.

Comment: @Hamsternik
MFC, строго говоря, это даже не библиотека, а фреймворк. Т.е. каркас приложение там генерится через виззарды. wxWidgets умеет не только в гуй, но и в сеть, файловые операции и многое другое. Она кроссплатформенна, да, можно ее и под MSVS. Ахиллесова пята - документации очень мало.

Кроссплатформенные гуй-библиотеки славятся тем, что они прячут платформенно зависимый код (тот же WinAPI). Т.е. в идеале, ты можешь линуксовый код в три движения перекомпилить для виндовс. Пример тому - всякие FileZilla, Code::Blocks и т.п.

Comment: @Hamsternik
Чтобы не уходить в ересь, скажу, что MFC для несложных интерфейсов в пару окон вполне подходит. Но по мне, слишком уж там много магии макросов, кодогенерации и близко к WinAPI для получения удовольствия.

Comment: Окей, спасибо! То есть, на сколько я понял, мне надо для начала что-то почитать по winAPI, а затем переходить к MFC?
Тогда вопрос на счет литературы - не подскажете, что почитать на тему winAPI, и в частности, MFC

Comment: @Hamsternik
Тут не знаю, что посоветовать. Знание хотя бы основ WinAPI лишним никогда не будет. Хорошие глубинные книги о технологиях пишет Рихтер. Для Windows это "Windows via C/C++" или "Создание эффективных Win32-приложений с учетом специфики 64-разрядной версии Windows" (Это разные издания одной книги, не помню, какая новее).

А по MFC - десятки книг разной степени паршивости) Могу посоветовать ресурс FirstSteps и, конечно же, MSDN (кстати, для WinAPI тоже более, чем актуально).

Answer (score 2):

MFC хорош тем, что

- большинство преподавателей больше
     ничем не владеют
- все методички в большинстве вузов написаны на MFC и по нему легко найти нужные вам кейсы.
- через MFC проще понять как работает WinAPI, а эти знания не будет лишними в будущем.

Comment: Со всем согласен, кроме крайнего пункта:

Через MFC ни только не проще понять WinAPI, но и сложнее, т.к. почти весь WinAPI, собсна, остается за кадром =)

Comment: Ага, понял, спасибо :)
Уже для себя решил начать изучать winAPI + MFC. Буду читать книгу "Системное программирование в среде Windows" - третье издание(Дж.М. Харт).
На сколько я понял, что это один из лучших вариантов хоть как-то ознакомится с winAPI
А на счет изучения самого MFC - я понял, что нужно сидеть на MSDN и смотреть там examples...

Comment: И такой вопрос - что-то по поводу C++\CLI есть у кого-то? Может тоже литературу какую-то по этому поводу посоветовать? 
Я так понимаю, что для изучения C++\CLI нужно на хорошем уровне знать OOП подход в С++. Просто если у меня пока немного знаний в ООП, я только вот как пару месяцев с ним разбираюсь...

Comment: @Hamsternik мой вам совет - не изучайте С++/CLI.

 Потому что  а) это совсем не С++ б) он вообще мало где нужен, и впоследствии вряд ли вам пригодится (я не видел ни одного программиста, для которого этот язык был бы основным, и вообще не уверен, что такие существуют в природе. Честно говоря, я даже не припомню, видел ли хоть одного программиста, который использовал этот язык)

Comment: @DreamChild, Герб Саттер, читая эти строки, расплакался бы))